# Same Program Runs Fine when ran from IDLE but not when ran directly

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a small Tkinter based GUI app on python. It worked fine when run with IDLE, but displays moduleError on running it directly. I am on windows. Running it directly means double-clicking the .py file. Here's the link to the code. I have the path to python appended in the PATH environment variable

http://codepad.org/ezxcpi7Y

And the error image:

[image: Error]

Why i am getting that error? Please help

Comment: first thing that comes to mind: what is the python path? print out `sys.path` path from within IDLE and cmd and compare

Comment: Note that you have a line... `tkinter.mesagebox.showinfo` in the code....

Comment: That's not causing problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `import tkinter.messagebox`

IDLE(writen in tk) imports this module in tkinter (python not imports modules twice).